# Javascript - setInterval for 2 auto slide on the same page

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create a auto slide for the slider using setInterval. It works like a charm when there's only one slider.

When there are 2 slider, the first slider wont work, and the second slider will slide faster, because there will be 2 setInterval and both are sliding the second slider. Anyway to make sure each setInterval slide their own slider?

```
var autoSlideTimer = 5;
var autoslide = setInterval(function () {

    if (autoSlideTimer == 0) {
        var slideMargin = offsetMarginLeft - width;

        if (-slideMargin == (width * totalImages)) {
            offsetMarginLeft = width;
            displayImage = 0;
        }

        slider.style.marginLeft = (offsetMarginLeft - width) + 'px';
        displayImage += 1;
        pagination = element.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        pagination.innerHTML = paginate;
        pagination.getElementsByTagName('li')[displayImage - 1].setAttribute("class", "displayed");

        slider = element.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

        offsetMarginLeft = parseInt(slider.style.marginLeft.replace('px', ''));

        autoSlideTimer = 5;
    } else {
        autoSlideTimer--;
    }
}, 1000);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work it out with another way, although is working but doesnt seems to be the perfect way

```
        var event = new Event('build');

        // Listen for the event.
        element.addEventListener('build', function (e) {

            function timeoutLoop()
            {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    if(autoSlideTimer == 0)
                    {
                        var slideMargin = offsetMarginLeft - width;

                        if(-slideMargin == (width * totalImages))
                        {
                            offsetMarginLeft = width;
                            displayImage = 0;
                        }

                        slider.style.marginLeft = (offsetMarginLeft - width) + 'px';
                        displayImage += 1;
                        pagination = element.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
                        pagination.innerHTML = paginate;
                        pagination.getElementsByTagName('li')[displayImage - 1].setAttribute("class", "displayed");


                        offsetMarginLeft = parseInt(slider.style.marginLeft.replace('px', ''));

                        autoSlideTimer = 5;
                    }else
                    {
                        autoSlideTimer--;
                    }
                    timeoutLoop();
                },1000);
            }
            timeoutLoop();
        }, false);

        // Dispatch the event.
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

At first, I used setInterval inside, yet the slider will be overwritten. But setTimeout is ok.